# Communication between Android devices

Tags: android, sockets, power-management

I'm looking for a way to allow a device to send secure notifications to another device with minimal battery loss. I am currently doing this using a SSLServerSocket however I feel like keeping a socket constantly open is very poor for battery life. The other option I considered was to just have a socket listening for a connection but I'm not sure if this is any better. I need the notifications to be sent instantly so using  a timer and connecting every x number of minutes is not optimal. Are there any good ways to achieve this over a wifi connection with minimal battery loss?

Comment: This really depends on what your application does, how often messages come in, why it must be p2p, etc. Try telling us a little more about what you're doing.

Comment: I'm forwarding sms messages from one device to another. Thus the importance of instant notification. And notifications can be sporadic.

Comment: If you keep wifi alive it drains battery.  It does not matter how you do it.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to do this then?

Comment: Realize that this will only work between mutually routable wifi networks - mobile networks generally do not support incoming connections (ie, supporting those would require a server both devices are in touch with, which starts to point to the C2DM idea mentioned in answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps you can use [C2DM](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html) (Cloud2DeviceMessaging). This may not be the perfect solution for you but instead of all the devices asking all the time for updates the server tells them they do.

Device A send a message to Device B -> Device A sends the message to the server -> Server notifies Device B that it has a message -> Device B asks the server for that message