# Android - Communication between Android devices via an app

Tags: android, django, communication

I am working on an Android app project where users of the app can communicate with each other. The communication should be done in audio (with their voices).
So, what I mean is the following scenario: When UserA speaks then its voice should be delivered to UserB in real-time.

I can imagine that this must be something like a client/server model. But how exactly.

What I did so far: 
I know how to send files like an image to a Django server by using the Django Rest Framework. Now I wanted to extend the functionality of my home project (which is an android app) by adding a kind of real-time audio chat app.

Can someone tell me which sources/topics I need to learn to be able to implement such functionality ? I have 0 knowledge about the whole server technologies out there and everything seems to be very complicated when you search in Google. I just worked with Django a little bit to learn how file upload is done because I could code in Python.

These posts [android communication between devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564553/android-communication-between-devices) and [Communication between Android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307625/communication-between-android-devices) were not what I looked for.

So, I would thankful for any advice in which direction I should go.

Comment: If you are building a VOIP app, then SIP (for example [pjsip](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android)) and [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/) are the options.

Comment: This looks more like real time chat. Firebase would perfectly suit this use case. You can take a look at https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firechat and https://medium.com/@meetpatel12121995/realtime-chat-using-firebase-database-b65ee23f3b6a and https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase--cms-27397. Instead of text it would be voice in your case. Firebase database would come in handy

Comment: @Dinesh Thanks. The Firebase stuff looks very good. But would it also be possible with Django as backend. I have already implemented authentication/login etc in Django. Jumping to Firebase would mean that that work was a waste in terms of time .

Comment: I don't have idea about Django. I wish I could help you out .